# LinkButton event not firing when <form action> attribute is set

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, linkbutton

I have a form action in an ASCX page set to an external URL

`<form id="fLoginForm" runat="server" action="http://external.url" method="post" defaultbutton="bSignIn">`

Inside there is a standard ASP linkbutton

`<asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn" ID="bSignIn" runat="server" Text="Sign In" OnClick="bSignIn_Click" />`

The event "bSignin_Click" never gets fired when I have `action="http://external.url"` set on the form tag.  However when I remove the action, it works as expected.  I thought for `runat='server'` forms, the form would always post back? I need to read the URL from the action attrib and then redirect to it with some hidden input values also in the page.

Thanks.

Comment: ascx's are user controls.  These should NOT have a form embedded in them.  Having a form in a user control can cause weird and unexpected behavior depending on the browser used.  Never mind that nested forms aren't valid html anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you click on the link button, your form will postback to handle the click event. On form action you have given action url and it will be redirected to your action URL.

Logically you are doing wrong, you have to remove action URL

Answer (score 1):

Why not handle the sign-in functionality within the handler `bSignIn_Click()`?

And then redirect the user to the desired URL using `Response.Redirect("http://external.url");`

Answer (score 1):

Well the behaviour was actually very weird, as it behaved completely differently on a colleagues machine - rechecking in the solution from SVN, and it worked. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

With the form you have, when the Linkbutton is clicked, all the data in your form is posted to the URL, and not posted back to the same form (hence the term "postback") where you can handle all those events.

You can try writing that URL in a hidden field (instead of form action attribute) and read that hidden field value in codebehind.